# generator-cg-angular grunt serve stuck at watch task

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

Just installed a new and fresh angularJS application based on Yeoman's generator-cg-angular.  After typing `grunt serve` I have the normal following stack:

```
$ grunt serve
Running "dom_munger:read" (dom_munger) task

Processing index.html
Wrote script[data-concat!="false"].src to dom_munger.data.appjs
Wrote link[rel="stylesheet"][data-concat!="false"].href to dom_munger.data.appcss

Running "jshint:main" (jshint) task
>> 5 files lint free.

Running "connect:main" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9001

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

You can see that my problem is with the "watch" task.  I had a yeoman's generator-angular project that always worked as expected when I called `grunt serve`with it but now with generator-cg-angular, this one call doesn't work.

Note that `grunt build` and `grunt test` work perfectly.  Only have problem with the `grunt serve` command.

Here is my Gruntfile.js content if someone can pin point the problem.

I'm assuming the problem starts on this line: `grunt.event.on('watch',...` but have no clue how to resolve it.

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var pkg = require('./package.json');

//Using exclusion patterns slows down Grunt significantly
//instead of creating a set of patterns like '**/*.js' and '!**/node_modules/**'
//this method is used to create a set of inclusive patterns for all subdirectories
//skipping node_modules, bower_components, dist, and any .dirs
//This enables users to create any directory structure they desire.
var createFolderGlobs = function(fileTypePatterns) {
  fileTypePatterns = Array.isArray(fileTypePatterns) ? fileTypePatterns : [fileTypePatterns];
  var ignore = ['node_modules','bower_components','dist','temp'];
  var fs = require('fs');
  return fs.readdirSync(process.cwd())
          .map(function(file){
            if (ignore.indexOf(file) !== -1 ||
                file.indexOf('.') === 0 ||
                !fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
              return null;
            } else {
              return fileTypePatterns.map(function(pattern) {
                return file + '/**/' + pattern;
              });
            }
          })
          .filter(function(patterns){
            return patterns;
          })
          .concat(fileTypePatterns);
};

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // load all grunt tasks
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
      main: {
        options: {
          port: 9001
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      main: {
        options: {
            livereload: true,
            livereloadOnError: false,
            spawn: false
        },
        files: [createFolderGlobs(['*.js','*.less','*.html']),'!_SpecRunner.html','!.grunt'],
        tasks: [] //all the tasks are run dynamically during the watch event handler
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      main: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        src: createFolderGlobs('*.js')
      }
    },
    clean: {
      before:{
        src:['dist','temp']
      },
      after: {
        src:['temp']
      }
    },
    less: {
      production: {
        options: {
        },
        files: {
          'temp/app.css': 'app.less'
        }
      }
    },
    ngtemplates: {
      main: {
        options: {
            module: pkg.name,
            htmlmin:'<%= htmlmin.main.options %>'
        },
        src: [createFolderGlobs('*.html'),'!index.html','!_SpecRunner.html'],
        dest: 'temp/templates.js'
      }
    },
    copy: {
      main: {
        files: [
          {src: ['img/**'], dest: 'dist/'},
          {src: ['bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**'], dest: 'dist/',filter:'isFile',expand:true}
          //{src: ['bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils-ieshiv.min.js'], dest: 'dist/'},
          //{src: ['bower_components/select2/*.png','bower_components/select2/*.gif'], dest:'dist/css/',flatten:true,expand:true},
          //{src: ['bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'], dest: 'dist/'}
        ]
      }
    },
    dom_munger:{
      read: {
        options: {
          read:[
            {selector:'script[data-concat!="false"]',attribute:'src',writeto:'appjs'},
            {selector:'link[rel="stylesheet"][data-concat!="false"]',attribute:'href',writeto:'appcss'}
          ]
        },
        src: 'index.html'
      },
      update: {
        options: {
          remove: ['script[data-remove!="false"]','link[data-remove!="false"]'],
          append: [
            {selector:'body',html:'<script src="app.full.min.js"></script>'},
            {selector:'head',html:'<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.full.min.css">'}
          ]
        },
        src:'index.html',
        dest: 'dist/index.html'
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      main: {
        src:['temp/app.css','<%= dom_munger.data.appcss %>'],
        dest:'dist/app.full.min.css'
      }
    },
    concat: {
      main: {
        src: ['<%= dom_munger.data.appjs %>','<%= ngtemplates.main.dest %>'],
        dest: 'temp/app.full.js'
      }
    },
    ngmin: {
      main: {
        src:'temp/app.full.js',
        dest: 'temp/app.full.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      main: {
        src: 'temp/app.full.js',
        dest:'dist/app.full.min.js'
      }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      main: {
        options: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeComments: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
        },
        files: {
          'dist/index.html': 'dist/index.html'
        }
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      main:{
        files: [{
          expand: true, cwd:'dist/',
          src:['**/{*.png,*.jpg}'],
          dest: 'dist/'
        }]
      }
    },
    karma: {
      options: {
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [  //this files data is also updated in the watch handler, if updated change there too
          '<%= dom_munger.data.appjs %>',
          'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
          createFolderGlobs('*-spec.js')
        ],
        logLevel:'ERROR',
        reporters:['mocha'],
        autoWatch: false, //watching is handled by grunt-contrib-watch
        singleRun: true
      },
      all_tests: {
        browsers: ['PhantomJS','Chrome','Firefox']
      },
      during_watch: {
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
      },
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build',['jshint','clean:before','less','dom_munger','ngtemplates','cssmin','concat','ngmin','uglify','copy','htmlmin','imagemin','clean:after']);
  grunt.registerTask('serve', ['dom_munger:read','jshint','connect', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('test',['dom_munger:read','karma:all_tests']);

  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    //https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/156

    var tasksToRun = [];

    if (filepath.lastIndexOf('.js') !== -1 && filepath.lastIndexOf('.js') === filepath.length - 3) {

      //lint the changed js file
      grunt.config('jshint.main.src', filepath);
      tasksToRun.push('jshint');

      //find the appropriate unit test for the changed file
      var spec = filepath;
      if (filepath.lastIndexOf('-spec.js') === -1 || filepath.lastIndexOf('-spec.js') !== filepath.length - 8) {
        spec = filepath.substring(0,filepath.length - 3) + '-spec.js';
      }

      //if the spec exists then lets run it
      if (grunt.file.exists(spec)) {
        var files = [].concat(grunt.config('dom_munger.data.appjs'));
        files.push('bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js');
        files.push(spec);
        grunt.config('karma.options.files', files);
        tasksToRun.push('karma:during_watch');
      }
    }

    //if index.html changed, we need to reread the <script> tags so our next run of karma
    //will have the correct environment
    if (filepath === 'index.html') {
      tasksToRun.push('dom_munger:read');
    }

    grunt.config('watch.main.tasks',tasksToRun);

  });
};
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Watch is suppose to continue running. It's monitoring the code for changes to be pushed via live reload. Navigate to http://localhost:9001 in your browser and you should see our app

Comment: ahhh.  thanks for the info!  I didn't tried to open the browser and check because I tough the behavior would be the same than with generator-angular, which also opens the browser when doing grunt serve.  My bad.  Thanks for the now-obvious hint! ;)

Comment: Its working weird: Sometime I change things in a html file and hit save but the watch doesn't change in the terminal and there is no browser reload.

Comment: I've noticed `<!-- Livereload script for development only (stripped during dist build) -->
  <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js" data-concat="false"></script>` in index.html so it reloads only when this page is touched (as for html files) but is it possible to watch all the newly created html files without inserting the above code in each of them?